# Is Peerjs only for one to one webrtc ?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc, peerjs

- I need to implement a one to many audio communication using webrtc . Is peerjs is apt for this ?
- I am alredy using socketio with nodejs . Is this enough for webrtc ?
- Please suggest some options to implement one to many communication using webrtc.
  I am a beginner in webrtc.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a one-to-many webrtc session with PeerJS, as every peer gets its own unique peer id. 
You can pass your grabbed MediaStream to each of the peers you want to communicate with.

I would suggest you to write a one-to-one application and then try to extend it to one-to-many, as you have to understand whats going on in WebRTC first.

SocketIO: You can use Socket.io for the signaling part of WebRTC, PeerJS already has that built in itself. Look for PeerServer Cloud...

Comment: One-to-a-few maybe. I suspect it's going to be mesh calls, and not scale well.

Comment: @kangaro0 I created one to one communication and one to many. One to one is working fine when i connects the third peer the second and third peer starts the communication (audio streaming) and the first one won't gets the audio stream from both the peers, but the first client is still connected to the peers.

Comment: Do you mean the first client is still connected to the signaling peer?

Comment: @kangaro0   The first client is connected but the  second and third client only gets the streaming, when the third client is joined to that session.